# Microsoft dynamics CRM 2011 : error 404 after moving my database

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I just moved my database from my development server to my deployement server. I used this tutorial from microsoft to do so : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699772.aspx#Move_databases_to_another_SQL

However when I try to launch the application, I have a 404 error. I tried everything, even reinstalling the CRM with the good SQL server configuration. But when I try to retrieve the configuration I made during the development, I still have the 404 error.

My development database was on a SQL server 2008 R2 10.50.2550 installed on a windows server 2008.
My deployement database (the new one) is on a SQL server 2008 R2 10.50.1600 installed on a windows server 2008 (another server on the same domain)
My CRM is a CRM 2011 on rollup 14 ( version of my organization : 5.0.9690.3557 )

Hope someone will help me !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried IIS Reset. Also make sure all CRM services are running.

Comment: Yes I tried iisreset but it did not work. And all CRM services are running.

Comment: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa7ad1aa-1f4e-4ba6-b622-a4fd801a3ab6/crm-2011-404-file-not-found-after-reinstall-rollup-6

Comment: I did not really follow all the step of your link, but now it works again. I just had to re-install the rollup 14.

Thank you very much

Comment: Great... Glad it helped you a bit

Comment: I will add this as a answer, so that it can help others if anyone came across the same issue. I am also planning for Roll-up 14, might be a help for me as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try IIS Reset and also make sure that all CRM services are running.

**Edit**

Re-installing the Rollup 14 helped the user to fix the issue.